# Convert a key value pair in a column as new column in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I want to parse a column, and get the key-value pair as column

**Input:**

I have a dataframe (called df) with the following structure:

```
ID data
A1  {"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":1}},"name":{"score":1}}}"}
A2  {"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":0.934}},"name":{"score":0.952}}}"}
```

**Expected Output:**

I wanted to create new column called 'score' and get the value from the key value pair

```
ID score1 score2
A1  1     1
A2  0.934 0.952
```

**Attempted Solution:**

```
data_json = df['data'].transform(lambda x: json.loads(x))
df['score1'] = data_json.str.get('userMatch').str.get('match').str.get('phone').str.get('name').str.get('score')
df['score2'] = data_json.str.get('userMatch').str.get('match').str.get('phone').str.get('name').str.get('name').str.get('score')
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series
```

**Notes:**

I am not even sure how to get the next score2

Comment: why are you doing data_json = df['data'].transform(lambda x: json.loads(x)). You have already read as json. Have you tried without it?

Comment: can you also post the dtypes?

Comment: Since the data column seems to contain a dict with a single key= "UserMatch" and a single value composed of a string (i.e.) ```"{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":1}},"name":{"score":1}}}"``` you could use regex to parse out the score values.

Comment: @Dieter yes,ID->string and data->object

Comment: @Epsi95 Yes I tired, got the error 'Can only use .str accessor with string values!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mu previous though regarding using regex, this is how I would approach your problem:

```
import re
def getOffset(row, offset):
    vals = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", row.data['userMatch'])
    if len(vals)> offset:
        return vals[offset]
    return None
df['score1'] = df.apply(lambda row: getOffset(row, 0), axis= 1)
df['score2'] = df.apply(lambda row: getOffset(row, 1), axis = 1)
df.drop(['data'], axis= 1, inplace=True)
```

This yields a dataframe of the form:

```
    ID  score1  score2
0   A1  1       1
1   A2  0.934   0.952
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty, but works with `split()`. Couldn't get a dictionary to be read, kept getting invalid syntax or missing delimiter.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''ID  data
A1  {"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":1}},"name":{"score":1}}}"}
A2  {"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":0.934}},"name":{"score":0.952}}}"}'''), sep='  ', engine='python')

df['score1'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: x.split('{"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":')[1].split('}', 1)[0])
df['score2'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: x.split('{"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":')[1].split(',"name":{"score":')[1].split('}', 1)[0])
```

Output:

```
   ID                                                                                  data score1 score2
0  A1          {"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":1}},"name":{"score":1}}}"}      1      1
1  A2  {"userMatch": "{"match":{"phone":{"name":{"score":0.934}},"name":{"score":0.952}}}"}  0.934  0.952
```